# How to use combobox item tcl tk

Tags: fonts, combobox, label, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have to change the font for a label's text by using a combobox code. 
This is my combobox:

```
variable varLabel3 
variable varCombobox1 [list Normal Italic Bold ]

ttk::combobox $base.combobox#1 \
    -values $varCombobox1
set c [.combobox#1 get]
```

For example if I choose `Italic`, the text from the label (`.label#1` in my program) gets inclined. How can I do this?

Comment: I get the feeling that you haven't been looking very hard in the documentation. Have tried doing anything with the `font` command, for instance? If you have, and your attempt doesn't work, I'd be glad to help once you've shown your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ttk::combobox` sends the *`<<ComboboxSelected>>`* virtual event to itself when its value changes, when you can use the combobox's *`get` method* to find out what was chosen and then act on that to configure the *named font* that you're using in the label. It doesn't take much code at all.

```
font create myFont -family Times -size 42 -weight normal -slant roman
pack [label .l -text "Sample Text" -font myFont]

set values [list Normal Italic Bold ]
pack [ttk::combobox .combo -values $values]
bind .combo <<ComboboxSelected>> {
    switch [%W get] {
        "Normal" { font configure myFont -weight normal -slant roman }
        "Italic" { font configure myFont -weight normal -slant italic }
        "Bold"   { font configure myFont -weight bold   -slant roman }
    }
}
```

You might want to also set the combobox's initial value and make it not directly editable as text:

```
.combo set [lindex $values 0]
.combo configure -state readonly
```

Everything else is just changing around how things are named.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  I also searched how could I change the font for the label' text by using a font chooser. It is on tcltk help site a code but it's useless. I mean that there are shown 4 procedures but can't figure it out how can them be used. The link is:https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/fontchooser.htm